# Regex match for string with multiple minus sign for htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

Current code for redirect `abc-def-32a-bb.jpg` to  `bb.jpg`
`RewriteRule ^test/(.+\-)(.+\-)(.+\-)(.+\.(jpg))$ /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/$4 [L]`
But this is not working. I think this is because of regex problem. Looks like (.+) includes the dash sign. I'm not sure how to fix this.
so here is some use cases.
`abc-def-12a-bb-sf2.jpg` >>> `bb-sf2.jpg`
`abc-def-12a-bb-sf2-fi3.jpg` >>> `bb-sf2-fi3.jpg`

So actually I need to match first only 3 dashes and only need string after the third dashes. Before third dash, the string could contain text(include non ascii characters) and numbers. And the string after third dash could contain any text and numbers (include dash and non ascii characters). 
Thank you

Comment: `.` is any character but a new line. You could do `[^-]+`. That is any character but a `-`. Also `-` is not special unless in a character class so it doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: @user3783243 so do you mean like this? `RewriteRule ^test/([^-]+\-)([^-]+\-)([^-]+\-)(.+\.(jpg))$ /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/$4 [L]` Or could you add full answer?

Comment: It works magically

Comment: I never tried it in htaccess, but in normal pcre regex, you can reference a capture group with `(?{n})` where `{n}` is the number of the group,  For example, this `([^-]+-)([^-]+-)([^-]+-)` can be done this way `([^-]+-)((?1))((?1))`  But like I said I don't know if that works in htaccess.. :-/

Comment: let me try @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: Good point, this worked @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: Cool, I use it in regular (regular, snickers) expressions all the time, saves repeating yourself, and it can make updating the repeated expression a bit easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer.
Thanks to @user3783243
`RewriteRule ^test/([^-]+-)([^-]+-)([^-]+-)(.+\.(jpg))$ /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/$4 [L]`
This worked perfectly.

Comment: Is there anyone who knows more exact result?

Comment: Please update the question with what you mean by `more exact`. It can be more exact but need more specifics.

Comment: Yes, now the string can contain any characters including special characters. so we need to prevent special characters like @, $, # ...

Comment: Maybe you want `\w+?-` that should be `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, or `_`.